# showing some values generated from the body of a psql function as done with console.log in ES2016

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

In ES2016 we can use console.log to print some values while we execute a function. Is there something similar for psql functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never heard of that thing called ES2016, but I assume that you are really talking about PL/pgSQL functions in PostgreSQL. `psql` is the command line client for that database.

To print output to the console in PL/pgSQL code, use `RAISE NOTICE`:

```
DO
$$BEGIN
   RAISE NOTICE '%, do you hear me?', current_user;
END;$$;
```

Comment: ES2016 is modern java script... Thanks